# Why do I have this mesh mask in Edit mode and how can I turn it off?

Tags: edit-mode

In *Edit Mode*, I have this mask that is a collection of vertexes. How do I turn it off?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: hello, what do you mean by mask? it looks like you have a highly subdivided mesh, no?

Comment: just press TAB to toggle between edit and object mode

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.